# where does fetchmail store mail?

Tags: command-line, backup, email, log, gmail

Trying to find where [downloaded](https://superuser.com/q/1222594/977796) messages [from](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/173249/204070) `Gmail` are [stored](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/363582/101935).  No mail in:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ ll /var/mail/nicholas 
-rw------- 1 nicholas mail 0 Nov 27 15:52 /var/mail/nicholas
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ ll /var/spool/mail/nicholas 
-rw------- 1 nicholas mail 0 Nov 27 15:52 /var/spool/mail/nicholas
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ cat ~/Maildir
cat: /home/nicholas/Maildir: No such file or directory
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ cat ~/MailDir
cat: /home/nicholas/MailDir: No such file or directory
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

The `.fetchmailrc` file:

```
set postmaster "saunders"
set daemon 60
set invisible
set postmaster administrator
set syslog
set logfile /var/log/fetchmail.log


set daemon 600
poll pop.gmail.com with proto POP3
   user 'saunders.nicholas@gmail.com' there with password 'xxx' is local_user here options ssl fetchlimit 400
```

from the log:

```
fetchmail: 357 messages for saunders.nicholas@gmail.com at pop.gmail.com (16640206 octets).
```

but I'm not seeing where it stores the downloaded messages.

What should I `grep` the log file for?

Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

The log shows:

```
fetchmail: awakened by signal 10
fetchmail: awakened at Fri 15 Dec 2023 05:05:56 AM
fetchmail: restarting fetchmail (/home/nicholas/.fetchmailrc changed)
fetchmail: starting fetchmail 6.4.27 daemon
fetchmail: 6.4.27 querying pop.gmail.com (protocol POP3) at Fri 15 Dec 2023 05:05:56 AM: poll started
fetchmail: Trying to connect to 142.250.107.109/995...connected.
fetchmail: Loaded OpenSSL library 0x30000020 newer than headers 0x30000010, trying to continue.
fetchmail: Server certificate:
fetchmail: Issuer Organization: Google Trust Services LLC
fetchmail: Issuer CommonName: GTS CA 1C3
fetchmail: Subject CommonName: pop.gmail.com
fetchmail: Subject Alternative Name: pop.gmail.com
fetchmail: pop.gmail.com key fingerprint: 4E:0E:B7:ED:C2:8E:3A:A4:AB:B8:1B:ED:80:44:C6:42
fetchmail: SSL/TLS: using protocol TLSv1.3, cipher TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 256/256 secret/processed bits
fetchmail: POP3< +OK Gpop ready for requests from 172.103.152.184 gy19mb186143720ivb
fetchmail: POP3> CAPA
fetchmail: POP3< +OK Capability list follows
fetchmail: POP3< USER
fetchmail: POP3< RESP-CODES
fetchmail: POP3< EXPIRE 0
fetchmail: POP3< LOGIN-DELAY 300
fetchmail: POP3< TOP
fetchmail: POP3< UIDL
fetchmail: POP3< X-GOOGLE-RICO
fetchmail: POP3< SASL PLAIN XOAUTH2 OAUTHBEARER
fetchmail: POP3< .
fetchmail: POP3> USER saunders.nicholas@gmail.com
fetchmail: POP3< +OK send PASS
fetchmail: POP3> PASS *
fetchmail: POP3< +OK Welcome.
fetchmail: POP3> STAT
fetchmail: POP3< +OK 357 16640206
fetchmail: POP3> LAST
fetchmail: POP3< -ERR Not supported
fetchmail: Not supported
fetchmail: POP3> UIDL
fetchmail: POP3< +OK
fetchmail: POP3< 1 GmailId102335023040492b
fetchmail: POP3< 2 GmailId1026101358f988a8
fetchmail: POP3< 3 GmailId102713517873dd8a
fetchmail: POP3< 4 GmailId1027142d4a18d59d
fetchmail: POP3< 5 GmailId10279b34b9241ac3
```

But [no mention](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/can-download-mail-through-fetchmail-but-where-does-it-go-617145/) of where the messages are stored.

see also:

https://stelfox.net/blog/2013/11/backing-up-gmail-with-fetchmail/

so am looking at procmail.

Answer (score 1):

The [getmail](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/getmail.1.html) program may work better as it supports directly delivering to a Maildir or mbox folder – and also has a `--delete` option. ([mpop](https://marlam.de/mpop/) is another good option; it is POP-only though.)

By default, Fetchmail follows the 50-year-old tradition of outsourcing mail delivery to another program – it delivers the messages through the locally installed Mail Transport Agent (such as Postfix, Exim, or Sendmail) which then probably puts them in /var/mail or sometimes ~/Mail... or which outsources storage to a yet another program, the Mail Delivery Agent (such as Procmail, Maildrop, or Sieve).

The specific mechanism Fetchmail talks to the Mail Transport Agent is `/usr/sbin/sendmail`, or sometimes `/usr/lib/sendmail`. If you do have this program (it's always named 'sendmail' no matter which software it came with), use `dpkg -S /usr/sbin/sendmail` to find which package owns it, then check the system logs of the corresponding service. It might be that the service is not running, so messages are queued and forgotten.

(That being said, most users who *do* bother installing Postfix typically do the complete opposite configuration; they disable all local storage and route all messages *to* their personal Gmail...)

But it will be easier to skip the MTA completely and have Fetchmail directly call procmail/maildrop for the delivery into your ~/Mail; to do this, specify the `mda` option:

```
~/.fetchmailrc
defaults
        #mda "/usr/bin/procmail"
        mda "/usr/bin/maildrop"
```

Procmail uses an arcane but very widely documented filter format:

```
~/.procmailrc
LOGFILE=$HOME/.cache/procmail.log
VERBOSE=on
MAILDIR=$HOME/Mail
DEFAULT=$MAILDIR/

:0
$DEFAULT
```

Courier Maildrop is *slightly* more modern and its configuration looks like this:

```
~/.mailfilter
logfile "$HOME/.cache/mailfilter.log"

DEFAULT="$HOME/Mail"

# if (/^List-Id:/)
#         to $DEFAULT/.Lists/

to $DEFAULT
```

Comment: I just removed postfix, so, this looks quite helpful.

Comment: is getmail in a standard repo?  I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Ubuntu has it as [getmail6](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=getmail) in their 'universe' repository.

Comment: getting getmail6 so thx.  There were no resuts from Marc for the mailing list in 2023, and no reply, so the mailing list seems dead tho.

Comment: just figuring out the syntax for the target mbox https://askubuntu.com/q/1497178/847449