# How to determine what's listening to port 25 on localhost?

Tags: command-line, email, port-forwarding, smtp, netstat

How do I determine what's running on port 25 below?

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ ss -tlpn sport 25
State                   Recv-Q                  Send-Q                                   Local Address:Port                                    Peer Address:Port                  Process                  
LISTEN                  0                       100                                          127.0.0.1:25                                           0.0.0.0:*                                              
LISTEN                  0                       100                                              [::1]:25                                              [::]:*                                              
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

Can I trace this using `ps` somehow?

In the context of:

[where does fetchmail store mail?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1497114/847449)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've passed the `-p` (`--processes`) flag to `ss` - but the `Process` column is empty because you don't have sufficient privileges. However

```
sudo ss -tlpn sport 25
```

should show something like `users:(("master",pid=1546,fd=13))`. Alternatively (again with elevated privileges)

```
sudo lsof -i :25
```

You can then interrogate using the PID from above ex.

```
systemctl status <PID>
```

or (if it is not a systemd service)

```
ps -fp <PID>
```

or for information about the process hierarchy if you have installed `pstree`

```
pstree -s -p <PID>
```