# How to specify a target mbox over IMAP with getmail?

Tags: command-line, archive, gmail, imap, mbox

[Looking](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wor/getmail/master/docs/getmailrc-examples) to use `getmail6` with IMAP and mbox to [archive](https://askubuntu.com/q/1497114/847449) gmail:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ getmail
Configuration error: configuration file /home/nicholas/.config/getmail/getmail incorrect (path: specified mbox file "~saunders/GotMail/inbox" does not exist)
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ cat .config/getmail/getmail 

[options]
verbose = 1
delete = false
message_log = ~/.getmail/log
message_log_verbose = true



[retriever]
type = SimpleIMAPRetriever
server = pop.gmail.com
username = saunders.nicholas
password = xxx
#mailboxes = ("INBOX")

[destination]
type = Mboxrd
path = ~saunders/GotMail/inbox
user = saunders 
  
#path = ~jeffp/Mail/inbox
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

Nothing in the log file.

I've tried many variations with the destination path.

Comment: ~/Directory/file as normal.  The example had this odd other pattern which doesn't work.   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wor/getmail/master/docs/getmailrc-examples